# How to work Elasticsearch in relational database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-5

I have two table
**company** and **managers** and the relation is **company** ***belongsTo*** **managers**.

**company** table contains

- id
- name
- phone
- address
- manager_id

and **managers** contains

- id
- name
- address

How to create elasticsearch index here??

And I need search company details from

1. Company name
2. Managers name

Answer (score 0):

You need to de-normalize the data for storing it in elasticsearch. You could obviously use parent-child relationships in elasticsearch too, but i don't see the point here since you need to search for the company/manager names. 
You can store it in a companies index like so:

```
Companies/company_id
{
   "name": <company_name>,
   "phone": <phone>
   ..,
   "manager_name": <manager_name>,
   ...
}
```

You might use the company_id as the elastic_id for your documents as it is easier to update them.
So you should be able to write a script that reads the companies from your DB (with the necessary relationships loaded, obviously) and syncs them to elasticsearch. You can propagate changes to companies/managers by hooking to your DB saves or through a cron job.

Hope this helps.